# How to start GUI with startx command (not found)

Tags: raspbian, startx

I am trying to start the desktop with Raspbian Stretch, but I'm not able to run `startx`.

I install: **RASPBIAN STRETCH WITH DESKTOP** 
from 
https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/

and then:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

I2C: enable, SSH: enable

localisation: prague

hostname: opensprinkler

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install git // github
sudo apt-get install mc // midnight commander
sudo apt-get install i2c-tools // for support I2C
sudo apt-get install python-smbus // for smbus support
```

(I followed the instructons from [here](https://pihrt.com/elektronika/248-moje-rapsberry-pi-zavlazovani-zahrady))

When I type `startx`, I get back:

```
bash-: startx command not found
```

Please do you have any suggestions?

(I want to continue with OpenSprinkler)

Comment: Odd, I thought the GUI started automatically with Raspbian. Are you absolutely sure this is the desktop version? Is there any output from `dpkg -l | grep raspberrypi-ui-mods`?

Comment: I am not 100% sure because I download by mistake both version :(               

Pls how can I see which Version I installed?

Comment: @palo Please try running the command I gave you; it'll tell you whether the Pi has the GUI package installed as expected (if there's no output, the GUI isn't installed)

Comment: here https://webshare.cz/#/file/5qg4cl5c24 you can see photo. 

(how can I copy or send linux text  from raspberry to mail or windows?)

Comment: @Aurora0001 
here is https://webshare.cz/#/file/3G13zd78z7 photo of my screen. it is ok?

Comment: @palo Looks like you mistyped the command, you must type all of the following in one line: `dpkg -l | grep raspberrypi-ui-mods` (note the thing after `dkpg` is a lower case L, not a 1). The line is the [pipe character](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/p/pipe.htm) which you need to use

Comment: @Aurora0001 aha thanks. new link: https://webshare.cz/group/5Xa6856cj6/  photo screen

Answer (score 4):

The fact that `dpkg -l | grep raspberrypi-ui-mods` doesn't output anything indicates that you probably do **not** have the desktop version installed. You certainly don't have the default Raspbian PIXEL packages on your system.

Since you have no GUI, you don't have startx either. The GUI starts automatically on the full version of Stretch with Desktop, so it is another suspicious sign that no GUI starts on your installation.

You can either:

- [Install the GUI packages on your existing system](https://gist.github.com/kmpm/8e535a12a45a32f6d36cf26c7c6cef51) (only the 'Adding GUI' section is really important)
- Reinstall using the full Raspbian Stretch/Buster (not Lite) version.

Comment: -*-  
I tried: Adding GUI
-*-
sudo apt-get install -y raspberrypi-ui-mods rpi-chromium-mods
sudo reboot
-*- 
ok?
-*-  
and  result from my screen :(
https://webshare.cz/group/4sC177Lk64/

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get -y install xinit` too, that package definitely contains `startx`.

Comment: :( 
https://webshare.cz/#/file/7f1Y0zl2fe    unable to fetch some archives. how can I try ... with --fix missing?

Comment: @palo "Temporary failure resolving ..." sounds like a potential network issue; is your network working normally?

Comment: yes! exactly network. Thank you! 
Cable Network was interrupted. 
Now after: startx 
https://webshare.cz/group/7h31l02pv1/    -*- 
how can I continue to start webrowser?  
-*- 
Then I will follow the instructons from: 
https://pihrt.com/elektronika/248-moje-rapsberry-pi-zavlazovani-zahrady  
-*- RaspbianStretchLiteOSPy_7_9_2017.img

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this problem not because I wanted `startx`, but because `startlxde` caused `cannot open DISPLAY` error.

To solve that, just install the package that contains `startx` with the command:

```
 apt-get install xinit
```

and then use `startx` instead of `startlxde`.

You might need to configure your `~/.xinitrc`.